# Excel vba .Interior.ColorIndex doesn't work properly

Tags: vba, excel

I have two cells: green and purple. I have the code:

```
Sub test()
    With Selection.Interior
        MsgBox (.ColorIndex)
   End With   
End Sub
```

Somewhy The `MsgBox` with number `15` appears both for green and purple colors. 
When I use the code

```
Sub test()
    With Selection.Interior
        MsgBox (.Color)
   End With
End Sub
```

It gives different number but unique for green and purple colors: `10213316` and `13082801`.

Why does the `ColorIndex` give the same numbers and why does `Color` give different and unique numbers?

Is it safe to use the numbers returned by `.Color` in code anyways? Wouldn't it change depending on computer?

Comment: FYI the parens around `.Color` are superfluous, and will eventually bite you in the rear end. [See why](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201705261415301545264).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Color` is a much wider palette than `.ColorIndex` (it has more colors defined). ColorIndex has to approximate to make up for fewer defined colors and shades of colors.

[image]